# Error generating projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xamarin.android

It's about a week that i installed eclipse and SDK and ...
but even when i open a new Hello World project and i want to run that eclipse shows this error:

```
Error generating final archive: Failed to create key: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
JAVA_HOME is set to: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Update it if necessary, or manually execute the following command:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey -alias AndroidDebugKey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 10950 -keypass android -keystore C:\Users\BEHZAD\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android
```

I also have some problems in Mono for Android.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Install **JDK** and set **JAVA_HOME** in environments variables to path that you **JDK** was installed. Currently it points to **JRE**.

Download [JDK](http://java-development-kit-jdk.en.softonic.com/) From Here.

Comment: I did that before but nothing happend :(