# P'roblem running Projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xamarin.android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error generating projects in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107807/error-generating-projects-in-eclipse)

It's about a week I installed eclipse and Android SDK .But when I wanna run my project (even when I open a new Hello World project), eclipse shows this error:

```
"Error generating final archive: Failed to create key: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

JAVA_HOME is set to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`
Update it if necessary, or manually execute the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey -alias AndroidDebugKey -keyalg RSA -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 10950 -keypass android -keystore C:\Users\BEHZAD\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android"
```

Even I can't open keytool.exe : `"Windows can't find 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\Keytool.exe ' make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again"`

I also have some problems with Keytool.exe in Mono for Android.

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME set correctly? Ie do you actually have Java in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7?

Comment: I was trying to edit that text but...

Comment: How can i set JAVA_home correctly i just did some thing about that but i'm not sure i did it right or not ...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is pretty common, a simple google search brings up lots:

[Tried many answers to get my keytool.exe to open but failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983946/tried-many-answers-to-get-my-keytool-exe-to-open-but-failed)

Further to that, I don't think you are using the keytool the way it is supposed to be used.

[How can I find and run the keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488339/how-can-i-find-and-run-the-keytool)

Answer (score 0):

please uninstall jdk then install jdk1.7 and check i thing problem solve. main error indicate the jdk problem .tyr it and tell me..all the best